# How to disable Datalabels in Navigator

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In my series I have one point with a datalabel. The label is shown in the navigator too. Is it possible to disable datalabels in the navigator?

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
navigator: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }   
    }
},
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Charissima/r56SP/1/

```
    series: [{
        name: 'mySeries',
            id : 'dataseries',
            color: 'blue',
            data:
            [   [1402351000000, 0.03], [1402392000000, 0.06], [1402398000000, 0.07],
                {   x: 1402401000000, y: 0.02,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        padding: -17,
                    }
                },
                [1402401600000, 0.07], [1402478400000, 0.08],
                [1402910400000, 0.05], [1402910450000, 0.04]
            ]   
    }]
});
```

Comment: If I change 'enabled:true' to 'enabled:false', it works fine. Your point 0.02 isn't showed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution is to use `dataLabels.formatter`, and display only for top series dataLabels, for example: http://jsfiddle.net/r56SP/5/

```
        dataLabels: {
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.series.xAxis.userOptions.id == "navigator-x-axis") {
                     return false;   
                }
                return this.y;    
            }
        }
```

About the problem root: navigator takes exact copy of data from first series. So all points are copied. Another workaround will be to set separate data(points) for navigator, like in [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.series).

Comment: It's me again. Your solution works, but I have many series with many points, so the dataLabels formatter has to do a lot and this takes time. Aren't there any options that can help me? I tried this, but it did not work.
    navigator: {
     plotOptions: {
      series: {
       dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
       }
      }     
     }
    },

Comment: I guess you prefer this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/r56SP/7/ Different formatter for navigator and different formatter for main series.